# Tool that lists all deprecated classes/methods that are no longer used anywhere?

Tags: java, deprecated, code-cleanup

I need to cleanup a some legacy code. Removing unused code is an important step.

Is there a tool that finds all deprecated code, removes all items which are still used somewhere and gives me a list of unused deprecated code?

For bonus points: Is there a tool which can find unused code non-deprecated code?

I'm aware that this is never perfect but I know for which cases I need special handling (as in DB drivers or classes that are referenced via DI).

Comment: Many years ago at a previous job they ran our code through a commercial obfuscator.  One of the things it did was remove classes and methods that weren't used - which meant you had to point out any classes or methods that might be invoked through reflection or that were API methods so that they didn't get removed or renamed.

Comment: Are you interested in methods which are annotated with an @Deprecated annotatino? If so, writing a tool which lists all annotated methods + corresponding classname should be fairly trivial (using Reflections).

Comment: @Helper: That's only 1% of the work. The hard task is locating all call sites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not completely certain that I understand your question. Do you want a tool that un-deprecates code that is still referenced? Any IDE will help you with that. Not automatically but removing an @Deprecated annotation is easily done with a global query-and-replace. After you have removed unused code, of course:

If all you want is to remove unused code, I have used the eclipse plugin [ucdetector](http://www.ucdetector.org/) for this purpose in a previous project. While it does not actually remove the unused code it does give you a list of the methods, classes and constants that have no references so you can remove them yourself. This is a good thing.

As you point out yourself, there are some classes/methods that may seem to be unused using static analysis. In my opinion this makes it impossible to automate this task. You the coder will have to analyze every block of code that is reported to be unused.

If you are lucky enough to have excellent test coverage another option is to use a code coverage analysis tool, like cobertura, clover or emma.

Comment: ucdetector seems to go in the right direction. First, I need all classes/methods which no one uses. Then, I can remove the public API from that. After that, I can check all the XML config files for classes which are still in use, etc.

Comment: I checked. ucdetector is what I need. It allows annotations, so I can document that something is still in use (and where).

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want, but ignores @Deprecated. I seem to remember it adds an option in the project's contextual menu to find unused methods.

http://eclipse-tools.sourceforge.net/

Comment: These tools have since been merged into Eclipse. Any idea where this ended up?

Comment: I haven't seen anything like that in 3.6.1.

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ identifies them as I write them.  I'm not sure if there's an option to remove them automatically.

Comment: For the whole project or only the current class? I.e. does it tell you about public methods that no one calls?

Comment: You can find usages in the entire project, but I think it's on a class by class, method by method basis.

Answer (score 0):

not sure your Q is a bit hard to grasp ... StackOverflow for me it is mostly about Code problem so I assume you want a way to get all Methods with the @Deprecated Annotation...

so basically you need to look into Java Reflection ..

So, for Example, let's say you want all the Deprecated Methods in the Date Class (Java.util.Date) this is what you can do ...

```
Class<?> clazz = Date.class; //Getting Class Obj of the Date Class

    Method[] methods = clazz.getDeclaredMethods(); //Getting methods


    for (Method m : methods) { //Inhanced For-Loop To get them-all 
        for (Annotation a : m.getAnnotations()) {
            if (a instanceof Deprecated) {
                System.out.println(m.getName()); // gitting the Methods Names
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: That doesn't tell whether anyone is still using this method.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [Spoon](https://github.com/INRIA/spoon/) library for transforming java source code:

```java
String path = "src/main/java";
Launcher spoon = new Launcher();
spoon.addInputResource(path);
spoon.setSourceOutputDirectory(path);
spoon.addProcessor(new AbstractProcessor<CtMethod>() {
        @Override
        public void process(CtMethod method) {
                if (method.hasAnnotation(Deprecated.class)) {
                        method.delete();
                }
        }
});
spoon.getEnvironment().setPrettyPrinterCreator(() -> {
                        return new SniperJavaPrettyPrinter(spoon.getEnvironment());
                }
);
spoon.run();
```

See [method `removeDeprecatedMethods`](https://github.com/INRIA/spoon/blob/8ff4eb442fc32dbda372aeec673d0b9f74b04e98/src/main/java/spoon/refactoring/Refactoring.java#L213).

Comment: This would also delete methods which are still being called by someone. How can I filter those out?

Comment: Yes, with a few more lines, created https://github.com/INRIA/spoon/issues/3195 for reference